# Angularjs - object not being passed to directive's scope for 2-way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is my directive:

```
app.directive("textareaInput", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/directives/textarea-input.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            inputName: '@',
            inputTitle: '@',
            rows: '@'
        }
    }
});
```

And this is my template:

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">{{ inputTitle }}</span>
    <textarea name="{{ inputName }}" rows="{{ rows }}" ng-model="model"></textarea>
</label>
```

When I use this:

```
<textarea-input input-title="Description" model="addingPiece.desciption" input-name="desciption" rows="4"></textarea-input>
```

the object 'addingPiece.description' is not put in the template. It just shows as 'ng-model="model">' in the DOM. This is working with other inputs, just not this one. Why is this not being used in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in attribute value of directive while passing `description` object in both places `model` as well as in `input-name`, It should be `description` instead of `desciption`

**Markup**

```
<textarea-input input-title="Description" model="addingPiece.description" 
input-name="description" rows="4"></textarea-input>
```

Comment: Thank you. This was driving me nuts.